# How to uppercase first letter after a hyphen, ie Adam Smith-Jones

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to uppercase the first letter/s of a string, including where the names are joined by a hyphen, such as adam smith-jones needs to be Adam Smith-Jones.

`ucwords()` (or `ucfirst()` if I split them into firstname, lastname) only does Adam Smith-jones

Comment: your making some large assumptions about names. http://old.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: very cute article, but the author is a software developer and not a db admin who has seen many real life cases. The db my client uses has numerous individuals with the above issue, it may not be Smith-Jones, but more like Salafi-Verjastani

Comment: You're making large assumptions about names. http://cowbelljs.blogspot.com/2012/01/whats-in-name-database.html

Comment: Could you give some *sample input* and *expected output* ?

Comment: read my question: "such as adam smith-jones needs to be Adam Smith-Jones"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
$string = implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $string)));
```

Comment: The correct way is to use `ucwords` instead of `ucfirst`. This will result in Adam Smith-Jones.

Comment: It's valid in this context.

Answer (score 12):

What do you think about the following code ?

```
mb_convert_case(mb_strtolower($value, "UTF-8"), MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

Please note that this also handles accented characters (usefull for some languages such as french).

Comment: even better:  mb_convert_case(mb_strtolower($value, "UTF-8"), MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 7):

Is this ok ?

```
    function to_upper($name)
    {
        $name=ucwords($name);
        $arr=explode('-', $name);
        $name=array();
        foreach($arr as $v)
        {
            $name[]=ucfirst($v);
        }
        $name=implode('-', $name);
        return $name;
    }
    echo to_upper("adam smith-jones");
```

Answer (score 4):

Other way:

```
<?php

$str = 'adam smith-jones';

echo preg_replace("/(-)([a-z])/e","'\\1'.strtoupper('\\2')", ucwords($str));

?>
```

Comment: The `/e` modifier is deprecated. Just use `preg_replace_callback()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* Uppercase words including after a hyphen
*
* @param string $text lower-case text
* @return string Upper-Case text
*/
function uc_hyphenated_words($text)
{
    return str_replace("- ","-",ucwords(str_replace("-","- ",$text)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     // note - this does NOT do what you want - but I think does what you said
     // perhaps you can modify it to do what you want - or we can help if you can
     // provide a bit more about the data you need to update
    $string_of_text = "We would like to welcome Adam Smith-jones to our 3rd, 'I am addicted to stackoverflow-posting' event.";
     // both Smith-Jones and Stackoverflow-Posting should result
     // may be wrong
    $words = explode(' ',$string_of_text);

    foreach($words as $index=>$word) {
       if(false !== strpos('-',$word)) {
          $parts = explode('-',$word);
          $newWords = array;
          foreach($parts as $wordIndex=>$part) {
            $newWords[] = ucwords($part);
          }
          $words[$index] = implode('-',$newWords);
       }
    }

    $words = implode(' ',$words);

?>
```

Something akin to this - **untested** - for the purposes of making sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can us '**ucwords**' to capitalize all words at once, and '**implode**' and '**explode**' together, like this:

```
ucwords(implode(" ", explode("_", "my_concatinated_word_string")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function capWords($string) {
    $string = str_replace("-", " - ", $string);
    $string = ucwords(strtolower($string));
    $string = str_replace(" - ", "-", $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that can convert all the words in a string to title case:

```php
function toTitleCase($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\w+/', function ($match) {
        return ucfirst(strtolower($match[0]));
    }, $string);
}
```