# How to Rename Uppercase Each Words with dash, underscore, brackets and capital words?

Tags: php, rename

I want to rename the following statement:

```
<?php
$sentence = "I-am-a-GOOD-programmer-(but-only-in-PHP)";
$do = ucwords($sentence);
echo $do;
?>
```

the above code will give output as:

```
I-am-a-GOOD-programmer-(but-only-in-php)
```

How do I get the output as:

```
I-Am-A-Good-Programmer-(But-Only-In-Php)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uppercase first letter after a hyphen, ie Adam Smith-Jones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977663/how-to-uppercase-first-letter-after-a-hyphen-ie-adam-smith-jones)

Comment: @harris - No, it's not a duplicate. That question only deals with hyphens, in the case of this question there's also brackets to consider, and possibly in context is would be other punctuation as well.

Comment: The variables may change, but the problem remains essentially the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202542/uppercase-each-first-letter-of-words-with-preg-replace also covers the same issue and can easily be expanded to cover whatever punctuation you could want.

Comment: Are you only interested in capitalizing words separated by hyphens and/or parentheses, or would you like to capitalize words in e.g. `[but only|in~PHP}` as well?

Comment: @Mark No. I don't wont any capital words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem:

```
<?php
$sentence = "I-am-a-GOOD-programmer-(but-only-in-PHP)";
$sentence = str_replace("-"," ",$sentence);
$do = ucfirst($sentence);
echo $do;
?>
```

Its gives output as I desired:

```
I Am A Good Programmer (But Only In Php)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sentence = "I-am-a-good-programmer-(but-only-in-PHP)";
$sentence = preg_replace_callback('/(^|[-(])(\w+)/', function ($match) { return $match[1] . ucwords($match[2]); }, $sentence );
var_dump($sentence);
```

will result in:

```
string(40) "I-Am-A-Good-Programmer-(But-Only-In-PHP)"
```

^|[-(] means the beginning or either a - or ( and can be easily expanded with any other chars you need, alternatively you could your \W, which means any non-word character.

\w+ means word-character (alphabetical characters).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php        
$msg = 'I-am-a-good-programmer-(but-only-in-PHP)';    
$msg_replaced = preg_replace_callback('#([^\w]*)?(\w+)([^\w]*)?#',     function($matched)    
{    
    return $matched[1] . ucwords($matched[2]) . $matched[3];    
}, $msg);    
echo $msg_replaced;//I-Am-A-Good-Programmer-(But-Only-In-PHP)    
?>
```